# Configure error with pkgsrc trying to build xf86-video-intel

Tags: compile, netbsd

I am trying to build xf86-video-intel driver on NetBSD 64bit, and I have this problem:

```
checking whether to build Xorg PCI functions... checking for PCIACCESS... no
configure: error: Package requirements (pciaccess >= 0.12.901) were not met:

Requested 'pciaccess >= 0.12.901' but version of pciaccess is 0.12.1

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

This is kind of awkward, since the package being looked is installed with the correct version:

```
# pkgin in libpciaccess
calculating dependencies... done.

nothing to upgrade.
1 packages to be installed: libpciaccess-0.13.2 (31K to download, 91K to install
)

proceed ? [Y/n] y
downloading packages...
libpciaccess-0.13.2.tgz             100%   31KB  30.5KB/s  30.5KB/s   00:01
```

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the pkgsrc tree is a mess. I solved the problem by compiling the package:

```
modular-xorg-server
```

This brings me a bit closer to running NetBSD with intel graphics.